# Efficient object creation with Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, jruby

First, I'm a Ruby and Sinatra noob so be gentle.

I am working on an application which is being deployed on Tomcat using JRuby and Sinatra. So far it seems to be going pretty well. However, I am struggling on what appears to me to be a waste of resources and potential time in the eventually deployed application. For every request for a particular route I am creating an object that connects to an sqlite3 database, querying the database and then closing the connection. I feel it would be more efficient to create a single object and share it across the routes. The object I would like to share is the AppData object so that when the user drills down into the initial list of logs or errors, I can use the same object to query for the detail view.

```
post "/log" do
@date = "#{params[:date].slice!(6..9)}#{params[:date].slice!(0..1)}#{params[:date].slice!(1..2)}"
app_data = AppData.new
if params[:log_type] == 'E'
  @log_type = 'errors'
  @data = app_data.get_errors :date => @date 
  app_data.close
  erb :log
else
  @log_type = 'warnings'
  @data = app_data.get_warnings :date => @date
  app_data.close
  erb :log
end
end

#detail view
get "/log/:log_type/:date/:item" do
app_data = AppData.new
if params[:log_type] == 'errors'
  @log_type = 'errors'
  @data = app_data.get_error_orders_for_item :date => params[:date], :item => params[:item]
else
  @log_type = 'warnings'
  @data = app_data.get_warning_orders_for_item :date => params[:date], :item => params[:item]
end
  app_data.close
  erb :log_details
end
```

Comment: you could store some stuff in a session but other than that you will have to query it again.

Comment: Thanks...Is there a way to keep the same object? I tried an instance variable but it seems to lose scope from route to route.

Comment: You could cache it but instance vars won't work. You could also write your results to a file and read it with every request.